# Get left and top of a text element inside an SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I want to get the `(top, left)` coordinate  of the `text` element relative to the `svg` element, expressed in the same unit/greatness as the `y` and `x` attributes of the `text` element.

I think that the example below is close, but there is a problem. `getBoundingClientRect` returns different values for `top, left` as the view port size changes, while of course the `y, x` attribute values of the `text` element are always the same. Thus the unit/greatness of `top, left` and `y, x` does not match.

I tried setting `display: flex` on the body to force the svg to not scale, but then it got the size 0 x 0.

```js
const svgRect = document.querySelector("svg").getBoundingClientRect()
const textRect = document.querySelector("text").getBoundingClientRect()

const textBoxPosRelativeToSvgExpressedInSvgCoordinates = {top: textRect.y - svgRect.y, left: textRect.x - svgRect.x}

console.log(textBoxPosRelativeToSvgExpressedInSvgCoordinates)
```

```html
<body>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 400">
        <g id="main">
          <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="#00c" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
          
          <polyline points="580,10 560,390 540,200 520,390 400,390" stroke="#c00" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none"/>
          
          <polygon points="350,75 379,161 469,161 397,215 423,301 350,250 277,301 303,215 231,161 321,161" stroke="#ff0" stroke-width="10" fill="#ffc"/>
          
          <rect x="100" y="10" width="150" height="100" rx="10" ry="20" stroke="#060" stroke-width="8" fill="#0f0"/>
          
          <circle cx="100" cy="300" r="80" stroke="#909" stroke-width="10" fill="#f6f"/>
          
          <ellipse cx="450" cy="50" rx="80" ry="30" stroke="#0cc" stroke-width="10" fill="#0ff"/>
          
          <text x="240" y="390" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="50" fill="#00f">SVG</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: you can call getBBox()

Comment: @RobertLongson: That doesn't work if the svg is scaled

Comment: Of course it does. Edit the question to explain what you're looking for with getBBox when it's scaled and what you're getting instead. Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: That's not getBBox(), it's getBoundingClientRect(). They are in different co-ordinate systems. One is local, the other is global.